# Improve Trie manipulation in Haskell code

Tags: haskell

I have the following data structure:

```
data XComposeString = XComposeString { keyEvents :: [Event], s :: Result }
  deriving (Eq, Show)

data XComposeFile = XComposeFile { strings :: [XComposeString] }
  deriving (Eq, Show)
```

Where `Event` and `Result` just `String` or some combination of several `String`.

I'm creating a `Trie` from list of type `[(keyEvents x, [s x])]`:

```
constructTrie list = M.fromListWith comp list
  where
    comp = \old new -> old ++ new
```

I want to check on duplicates and prefix overlaps.

```
duplicates :: M.TrieMap Map.Map Event [Result] -> String
duplicates m = M.showTrie list ""
  where
    list = M.filter (\v -> length v /= 1) m

prefixOverlap :: M.TrieMap Map.Map Event [Result] -> String
prefixOverlap m = M.showTrie list ""
  where
    list = M.filterWithKey (\k v -> not $ null $ catMaybes [M.lookup x m | x <- reverse (inits (init k))]) m
```

How can I improve this, so, there would be three functions: one to create, one to check on duplicates and one to check on prefix overlaps.

Useful imports and types definition:

```
import Data.List(inits)
import Data.Maybe(catMaybes)
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import qualified Data.ListTrie.Map as M

type Event = String
type Result = String
```

Also, `cabal install list-tries` is needed for `ListTrie` data structure.

Comment: Are you using [TrieMap](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/TrieMap) package?

Comment: @nponeccop: No, [Data.ListTrie.Map](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/list-tries-0.4.3/docs/Data-ListTrie-Map.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you add minimal imports so your code compiles? I had to guess:

```
import Data.ListTrie.Map as M hiding (null)
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import Data.Maybe
import Data.List


data Event = Event deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)
data Result = Result deriving (Show, Eq)
```

`constructTrie` can be easily improved by inlining `comp`:

```
constructTrie list = M.fromListWith (++) list
```

Or even to `constructTrie = M.fromListWith (++)` but that requires turning off monomorphism restriction or adding an explicit signature for `constructTrie`, so it's up to your taste.

Also you can deduplicate showTrie calls and long trie signatures:

```
mshow list = M.showTrie list ""

type ResultTrie = M.TrieMap Map.Map Event [Result]

duplicates :: ResultTrie -> String
duplicates m = mshow list
  where
    list = M.filter (\v -> length v /= 1) m

prefixOverlap :: ResultTrie -> String
prefixOverlap m = mshow list
  where
    list = M.filterWithKey (\k v -> not $ null $ catMaybes [M.lookup x m | x <- reverse (inits (init k))]) m
```

Now it's beneficial to inline `list` variables in both functions:

```
duplicates :: ResultTrie -> String
duplicates m = mshow $ M.filter (\v -> length v /= 1) m

prefixOverlap :: ResultTrie -> String
prefixOverlap m = mshow $ M.filterWithKey (\k v -> not $ null $ catMaybes [M.lookup x m | x <- reverse (inits (init k))]) m
```

Now you can get rid of `m` in `duplicates`:

```
duplicates :: ResultTrie -> String
duplicates = mshow . M.filter (\v -> length v /= 1)
```

In `prefixOverlap` the line is too long, I can split it. I chose to extract the `(\ -> )` construct. Note that m is in more that 1 place so we cannot use `.`.

```
prefixOverlap :: ResultTrie -> String
prefixOverlap m = mshow $ M.filterWithKey f m where
    f k _ = not $ null $ catMaybes [M.lookup x m | x <- reverse (inits (init k))]
```

Now remove extra parentheses in the comprehension:

```
prefixOverlap :: ResultTrie -> String
prefixOverlap m = mshow $ M.filterWithKey f m where
    f k _ = not $ null $ catMaybes [M.lookup x m | x <- reverse $ inits $ init k]
```

From here I'll only work on `f`.

Now a trickier part. Long chains of `$` are equivalent to `.` following one `$` in the end:

```
    f k _ = (not . null . catMaybes) [M.lookup x m | x <- reverse $ inits $ init k]
```

`not . null . catMaybes` is a function of `[Maybe a] -> Bool` that returns `True` only if there is any `Just` in the list. I can literally translate this sentence into Haskell: it's just `any isJust`:

```
    f k _ = any isJust [M.lookup x m | x <- reverse $ inits $ init k]
```

Now even trickier: your comprehension is just a `map`:

```
    f k _ = any isJust $ map (\x -> M.lookup x m) $ reverse $ inits $ init k
```

Congratulations, we can again turn a chain of `$` into a chain of `.`:

```
    f k _ = any isJust . map (\x -> M.lookup x m) . reverse . inits . init $ k
```

Now remember that `.` is associative so you can put parentheses in the middle of the chain wherever you want:

```
any isJust . (map (\x -> M.lookup x m) . reverse) . inits . init
```

Now we have `map something . reverse`. And it doesn't matter when you reverse - before or after map:

```
map something f . reverse = reverse . map something
```

That is, `map` and `reverse` commute and we can swap them and remove parens:

```
any isJust . reverse . map (\x -> M.lookup x m) . inits . init
```

Now we can put around `any` and `reverse`. It's clear that `any` works the same way for straight and reversed lists, that is, `any something . reverse = any something`, so we can throw `reverse` away:

```
any isJust . map (\x -> M.lookup x m) . inits . init
```

And put back into `prefixOverlap`:

```
prefixOverlap :: ResultTrie -> String
prefixOverlap m = mshow $ M.filterWithKey f m where
    f k _ = any isJust . map (\x -> M.lookup x m) . inits . init $ k
```

Here is the full version of the code:

```
import Data.ListTrie.Map as M hiding (null, map)
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import Data.Maybe
import Data.List

type Event = Char
type Result = ()
type ResultTrie = M.TrieMap Map.Map Event [Result]

data XComposeString = XComposeString { keyEvents :: [Event], s :: Result }
  deriving (Eq, Show)

data XComposeFile = XComposeFile { strings :: [XComposeString] }
  deriving (Eq, Show)

constructTrie list = M.fromListWith (++) list

mshow :: ResultTrie -> String
mshow list = M.showTrie list ""


duplicates :: ResultTrie -> String
duplicates = mshow . M.filter (\v -> length v /= 1)

prefixOverlap :: ResultTrie -> String
prefixOverlap m = mshow $ M.filterWithKey f m where
    f k _ = any isJust . map (\x -> M.lookup x m) . inits . init $ k
```

Note that I used fake `Event` and `Result` types. I also checked that old and new `prefixOverlap` are the same using QuickCheck and smallcheck libraries:

```
prefixOverlapOld :: ResultTrie -> String
prefixOverlapOld m = M.showTrie list ""
  where
    list = M.filterWithKey (\k v -> not $ null $ catMaybes [M.lookup x m | x <- reverse (inits (init k))]) m

prop_foo x = prefixOverlap m == prefixOverlapOld m where
    m = M.fromList $ map (first (++ "X")) x
```

`first` is from `Control.Arrow`.

The `prefixOverlap` probably can still be improved with using `lookupPrefix` and/or `children` functions from `Data.ListTrie.Map`.

Here is my take:

```
prefixOverlapNew :: ResultTrie -> String
prefixOverlapNew = mshow . M.unions . map (\(p,m) -> M.addPrefix [p] m) . Prelude.filter (\(p, m) -> M.size m /= 1 || (null $ fst $ head $ M.toList m)) . Map.toList . M.children1
```

Note that it differs from both original `prefixOverlapOld` and refactored `prefixOverlap`:

QuickCheck found that they differ on a map with 2 keys "fo" and "f". The `prefixOverlapNew`  version correctly shows both "fo" and "f" as they overlap. The original version(s) show only value on "fo" key which is dubuios.

Here is an improved version using list comprehension to combine filter and map:

```
prefixOverlapNew :: ResultTrie -> String
prefixOvelapNew mm = mshow $ 
    M.unions [M.addPrefix [p] m | (p, m) <- Map.toList $ M.children1 mm,  M.size m /= 1 || null (fst $ head $ M.toList m)]
```

Moved `f` out:

```
prefixOverlapNew mm = mshow $ M.unions [M.addPrefix [p] m | (p, m) <- Map.toList $ M.children1 mm, f m] where
        f m =  M.size m /= 1 || null (fst $ head $ M.toList m)
```

Finally, a version in list monad, just for fun:

```
prefixOverlapNew :: ResultTrie -> String
prefixOverlapNew mm = mshow $ M.unions $ do
        (p, m) <- Map.toList $ M.children1 mm
        guard $ M.size m /= 1 || null (fst $ head $ M.toList m)
        return $ M.addPrefix [p] m
```

`guard` is from `Control.Monad`.